# Ionic can't build project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am a beginner of the ionic.
When I use "ionic build android". It occurs the following errors:
[image]

But I had already installed android-22 and the latest SDK flatform-toos.
How to fixed it?
[image]

Comment: ionic platform add android it will be execute successfully?

Comment: yes, platform add android execute successfully.
I am taking a look at the link that you provide. But seems can't get any work solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take look of this one. follow these steps

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

Type in console "ionic platform remove android"
"ionic platform add android"
I had this problem myself :^)